# Unsupported handler method return type 'System.Int32 for Razor handler

Tags: c#, razor-pages

In my razor project and I want the handler to return an int but I keep getting this error `Unsupported handler method return type 'System.Int32'`. I can not seem to figure how to do this other than putting it inside a return type of content as a string. According to this [link](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods) it mention that `handler methods must be public and can have any return type` but is doesn't seem like it. Are hanlder only ment to return actionresult classe?

Comment: Please also post a code minimal reproducible example so we can help you

Comment: The link was incorrect. I've amended it. If you want to return an int, then you do need to wrap it in a `ContentResult` or a `JsonResult`.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks for clearing up the confusion.